# How to access the ASP.net website deployed in Windows Azure VM (IIS Server)

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I have installd IIS server in windows azure virtual machine using ARM template also deployed one application. But when I am accessing the DNS name/Public IP of my VM the default IIS server is coming. I am unable to access my website.

Please give some idea how to access the deployed website using DNS name or public IP.

I am following the below github template for application deployment:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-vm-dsc

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. If you can reach the VM via IP address and port 80, you've set things up correctly. The rest of it is up to you, to properly deploy your application and configure IIS (which is not related to Azure).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Visual Studio 2012 or higher, you can create `PublishProfile` and use the `Publish` feature in order to deploy your Web App to Azure service. Refer to the **Build->Publish** menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your website is reachable on port 80 but you have to [setup a VM endpoint](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints/) if you want your site to be published on another port than the default one.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the sample quickstart "as is" the problem is likely that you're missing the virtual application in the path (it's probably not the best sample).  If you're hitting the VM using an URI like this:

http://your-dns-name.westus.cloudapp.azure.com

You need to add the web app path onto the end, e.g.

http://your-dns-name.westus.cloudapp.azure.com/webapplication

You can double check the name of the web application by using IIS Manager on the VM, but I think that should be the default name for that quickstart sample.